# Programmatically Enable "allow scripting of microsoft webbrowser control" in Browser

Tags: javascript

I want to open browser print preview by using code. The issue is this code work on local machine but not live. So I need to function allow scripting of microsoft webbrowser control. It that possible I change the setting by code? Or other code for open print preview suggest? The error message I get is ExecWB is non a member of webbrowser.

```
            printPreview() {
            var OLECMDID = 7;
            /* OLECMDID values:
            * 6 - print
            * 7 - print preview
            * 1 - open window
            * 4 - Save As
            */
            var PROMPT = 1; // 2 DONTPROMPTUSER
            var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
            WebBrowser1.ExecWB(OLECMDID, PROMPT);
            WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
        }
```

Comment: ActiveX - rubbish from day one - what version of Internet Exploder do you wish to perform this print preview on?

Comment: @Jaromanda X IE 8 ++